# Abbreviate check function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm just starting to learn javascript and i'm trying to figure out how to make this code shorter.
Right now, the check function evaluates if a = "admin" and after that if a = "manager".
Is it possible to do this evaluation in one line?
Kind of "*if (a = "admin" or "manager")* ..."

```
const valid = "User name valid";
const invalid = "User name invalid";
function check(a, b) {
  if (a === "admin") {
    return valid;
  } else if (a === "manager") {
    return valid;
  } else if (b[0].toUpperCase() == b[0] && b.length > 4 && b.length < 10) {
    return valid;
  } else {
    return invalid;
  }
}
console.log(check("manager", "ikey"));
console.log(check("admin", "root"));
console.log(check("user", "ikey"));
console.log(check("user", "Mikey"));
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `a === 'admin' || a === 'manager'`.  A quick search engine search for javascript conditionals should have returned this information for you, without having to ask a question here.  This is basics of the language, or most languages in general.

Comment: Thanks!
I was trying to use the || operator already but wasn't doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical or operator to handle all valid cases together.

```
function check(a, b) {
  if (a === "admin" || a === "manager" || b[0].toUpperCase() == b[0] && b.length > 4 && b.length < 10) {
    return valid;
  } else {
    return invalid;
  }
}
```

You can also simplify this to one statement using the ternary operator.

```
function check(a, b) {
  return a === "admin" || a === "manager" || b[0].toUpperCase() == b[0] && b.length > 4 && b.length < 10 ? valid : invalid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with or operator || like so:

```
if (a === "admin" || a === "manager" || (b[0].toUpperCase() == b[0] && b.length > 4 && b.length < 10)) 
   return valid;
else 
    return invalid;
```